# REST API with MultipartFormDataInput returns 404 - Not Found

Tags: java, spring, api, rest

I have several APIs in TemplateResource interface, all APIs work well, except this one postFile.

```
@SecurityRequirement(name = "bearerAuth")
@Tag(name = "Template", description = "Operations related to Template")
public interface TemplateResource {

    @POST
    @Authorized
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Operation(summary = "Create a file.", responses = {
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "201", description = "File successfully created."),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "Invalid request provided."),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "401", description = "Access token is missing or invalid."),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "500", description = "An error occurred while processing request.", content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = java.lang.Error.class)))
    })
    @Path("/amt/v1/generatedFile/task/{taskId}/secondarysource/{secId}")
    Response postFile(
            @Parameter(in = ParameterIn.PATH, description = "The task identifier.", required = true) @PathParam("taskId") Long taskId,
            @Parameter(in = ParameterIn.PATH, description = "The secondary identifier.", required = true) @PathParam("secId") Long secId,
            @RequestBody(
                    description = "A file sent using multipart/form-data",
                    required = true,
                    content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = MultipartFormDataInput.class)))
                    MultipartFormDataInput input);
}
```

I have a class to implement this. To debug, I am trying to return a value.

```
@Authorized
@Path("/")
public class TemplateEndpointImpl extends RestServiceBase
        implements TemplateResource {

    @Override
    public Response postFile(Long taskId, Long secId, MultipartFormDataInput input) {
        return Response.ok("Test").build();
    }
}
```

When using swagger, I can see that it already printed out this API but when I try to use postman to test, it returns 404

Any idea what cause this error? and how to fix this?

Thanks for any comments/suggestions.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cndnf.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaQC2.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cndnf.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pI89m.png)

Comment: Can you show us the headers that are included in Postman call?

Comment: Thanks @JoãoDias. I attached the header as attached images.

Comment: It seems ok. If in Swagger you can call the API, then I don't understand the issue. Can you show us your Swagger?

Comment: I just added the print out swagger. Thanks for having a look.

Comment: Can you make a request in Swagger and show us the answer and also the generated request? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know how to make a request in Swagger with token? Where should I put the token?

Comment: That needs to be added to the code. But in that case, you also don't know if this is working in Swagger. Can you tell us which is the server URL that appears in Swagger UI?

Comment: You mean this?
http://localhost:8080/api/docs/index.html#/Template/postFile

Comment: No, I mean the server URL that Swagger would call. The one that your application exposes. My guess is that you are missing something in your path. Even with the simple `TemplateEndpointImpl` are you getting the same issue?

Comment: You mean this http://localhost:8080/amt/v1/generatedFile/task/654817/secondarysource/599294
or this
http://localhost:8080/amt/v1/generatedFile/task/{taskId}/secondarysource/{secId}
Just let you know that other APIs in this interface works well, except this one.

Comment: Then I don't understand. Could it be that 404 is in fact the response from your service?

Comment: Oops, you are totally right. The error comes from the URL. I should have something like localhost:8080/api/amt..... Lost some hours because my stupid mistake.

Comment: I will add this as an answer so that you can accept it and "close" your question ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check your URL, it seems to me that you are missing something in your path and that is why you are getting the 404 Not Found.